# Flag or mark a numeric value in PHP if it is 10th number from an array of numbers

Tags: php, numbers

I have an array in PHP with values like this

```
Array
```

(
    [49] => Array
        (
            [Profile] => 0.01
            [Value] => 220.3
            [Display] => 0
        )

```
[48] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 0.02
        [Value] => 220.6
        [Display] => 0
    )

[47] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 0.03
        [Value] => 220.9
        [Display] => 0
    )

[46] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 0.04
        [Value] => 221.2
        [Display] => 0
    )

[45] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 0.05
        [Value] => 221.5
        [Display] => 0
    )

[44] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 0.06
        [Value] => 221.8
        [Display] => 0
    )

[43] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 0.07
        [Value] => 222.1
        [Display] => 0
    )

[42] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 0.08
        [Value] => 222.4
        [Display] => 0
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 0.09
        [Value] => 222.7
        [Display] => 0
    )

...

[41] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => 1.00
        [Value] => 222.7
        [Display] => 0
    )
```

)

Now into a foreach

```
foreach ($grid as &$gridData) {
    $gridData['Display'] = is_grid_profile_10th_step ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I want from 10 to 10 steps in this array to set `[Display] => 1` such that values

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
...
0.9
1.0
```

to be marked with that `[Display]`.

Already tryed:

`$gridData['Display'] = ($gridData['Profile'] * 10) % 10 == 0 ? 1 : 0;` - this didn't work for me

`$gridData['Display'] = is_int($gridData['Profile'] * 10) ? 1 : 0;` - this didn't work too

but this did:
`$gridData['Display'] = intval($gridData['Profile'] * 10) == ($gridData['Profile'] * 10) ? 1 : 0;`

I have a feeling that there should be a more elegant way to do this in PHP.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a modulus calculation like this:

```php
// round to 1 decimal
$rounded = round($gridData['Profile'], 1); 

// Now check if the round changed the original value, if so, it was not
// a thenth number
$gridData['Display'] = $rounded == $gridData['Profile'] ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I changed 
`$mod = $gridData['Display'] % 0.1;` 
with 
`$mod = $gridData['Profile'] % 0.1;` 
but still didnt't work.

Comment: Sorry, I see the modulus with a decimal does not work in php. I'll update my answer